# React Native - error attachToServer is not a function

Tags: node.js, react-native

After command: npx react-native start

````
TypeError: attachToServer is not a function
    at Object.runServer [as func] (E:\WiemIleJem\WiemCoJem\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\start\runServer.js:131:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\WiemIleJem\WiemCoJem\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9) ```

It's clean project created by command: npx react-native init
````

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing [@react-native-community/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cli/v/7.0.1)

`npm i @react-native-community/cli --save-dev`

Comment: You are the best! Thanks, it works.

Comment: Does not solve for me, still having this issue. I see a recent react-native update about 2 hours ago. I suspect a bugged release. Trying with a previous one using `react-native init newproject --version X.XX.X`

Comment: Here's the GitHub issue to stay up to date.

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1561