# Can't start metro server "attachToServer is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

Looking at the original docs, I ran `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` and didn't change anything.

I get attachToServer is not a function error when I run `npx react-native start` or `yarn start`. Both don't work. I didn't have this issue before. I don't know what might be causing it. Using expo, I can start metro so this is probably a react-native cli issue.

Here are the package versions.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-native": "0.67.2"
},
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
  "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
  "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
  "eslint": "7.14.0",
  "jest": "^26.6.3",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
  "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
},
```

[image: The error screenshot]

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71174569/react-native-error-attachtoserver-is-not-a-function

Comment: @blindgaenger Thank you. Good timing for me then I literally just tried to do this but I was not able to find anything.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/318

Answer (score 0):

I think installing `@react-native-community/cli` can resolve your problem. try to the following command:

```
yarn add --dev @react-native-community/cli
```